# See what method was called on an object

Tags: python

Say I have the following:

```
obj = Object()
obj.meth(1, 2)
```

Inside `Object`, how can I detect what method was called on it and also its arguments? I was thinking about a magic method, but I have no idea on how to get both the called method name and its arguments. I am looking for something like:

```
class Object(object):
    def ????(self):
        print 'Method %s was called with args: %s' % (????, ','.join(???))
```

Basically, I need this for the following scenario: `obj` is some kind of proxy to another class, and all method calls to that "another class" should go through `obj`. So instead of calling `another_class.meth()` directly, `obj.meth()` is called. And since `Object` is abstract, it will stand as a proxy for different classes, hence it can't be known what methods will be called on it.

If there is any other better solution to this, please share!

Comment: So basically you want to do what the debugger does, except you can manipulate it in your application?

Comment: @frostnational it is not quite a duplicate, read carefully.

Comment: @AndreiHorak it's very similar

Comment: @AndreiHorak: Either you are asking about detecting arbitrary method access, or you are asking about detecting calls to *existing* methods.  If the former, Frostnational's dupe link is spot on. If the latter, you just told me it wasn't!

Comment: Alright, it seems I'm the one who misread the duplicate question. The answer indeed helps me. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreiHorak: ah, now we get to the core of your question; you don't want to trap method calls, you want to proxy an object.

Comment: Sounds like the Ruby equivalent of `method_missing`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how method access *works*. Methods can be looked up without being called too:

```
method = someobj.methodname

if some_condition:
     method()
```

Here the method is merely referenced, not called, until a condition is met. Methods are *just another object*, that happens to be callable.

For a proxy class, you don't trap method calls, you trap *attribute access*:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, real_obj):
        self.real_obj = real_obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.real_obj, name)
```

Comment: `meth` should not be present in `Object`, as it is now known what methods will be called on an `Object` instance. (downvote wasn't from me).

Comment: @AndreiHorak: That is **not clear** from your question; nowhere in your post do you state that you want this to work for arbitrary attributes.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: and it is never known what methods *will* be called, only what methods are available. :-)

Comment: I've edited my question, hope it will make things more understandable.

Comment: Okay. And after I capture the attribute, how do I call the trapped attribute from the proxied class with the given arguments?

Comment: You don't. The caller asks for the proxy for a method named `meth`. The proxy returns the method named `meth` that belongs to the `real_obj` value. Once the caller has a reference to the method, it is called directly.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that it will fail if a caller tries to find out if Object has a particular method. For instance, `Object("123").__len__()` succeeds, but `len(Object("123"))` fails as `len` checks for a `__len__` method.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon: that's not due to proxying, but because [special methods are looked up on the class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes). You have to work around that by implementing the custom methods on the class itself and explicitly proxying those calls.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: what are you trying to do with the call? You can return a proxy method from `__getattr__` too, if the retrieved attribute is a callable, if you need to intercept the call.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, solved my problem :)